# RabbitMq listening on random port after service restart

Tags: rabbitmq, windows-10, erlang

I've installed erlang - otp_win64_19.3 and RabbitMQ 3.7.4 versions. The installation shows a success. However, erl service listens on a random port. After restarting service the port changes. I tried to force with the following configuration -

```
listeners.tcp.1 = 127.0.0.1:5672
listeners.tcp.2 = ::1:5672
```

But this is not helping. I've installed RabbitMQ on Windows 10.

Comment: I found similar behaviour with the latest Erlang 22.1 and latest version of RabbitMQ 3.8.2

Comment: Is it listening on a random port in addition to or instead of port 5672?

Comment: It's listening on random port instead of 5672

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Please respond [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/6GBpVh16z5M/discussion)